# Horizontal line of 1px is not perfectly straight

Tags: html

I'm trying to test a simple little border style I made using `<hr>` html tags. It consists of vertical and horizontal lines. The vertical lines display perfectly but the horizontal lines have a tiny strange curve at the end, I'm not sure why it's happening. Does somebody know the problem?

here is my code:

```html
<div style="width:680px; height:540px; position: relative;">
  <hr style="height: 23%; width: 0.01em; position: absolute; left: 35.3%; top: 5.5%;">
  <hr style="height: 18%; width: 0.01em; position: absolute; left: 35.3%; top: 40.5%;">
  <hr style="height: 20%; width: 0.01em; position: absolute; left: 35.3%; top: 70.5%;">

  <hr style="height: 23%; width: 0.01em; position: absolute; left: 65.9%; top: 5.5%;">
  <hr style="height: 18%; width: 0.01em; position: absolute; left: 65.9%; top: 40.5%;">
  <hr style="height: 20%; width: 0.01em; position: absolute; left: 65.9%; top: 70.5%;">

  <hr style="width: 22%; height: 0.01em; position: absolute; left: 7.7%; top: 34.5%;">
  <hr style="width: 19%; height: 0.01em; position: absolute; left: 41.2%; top: 34.5%;">
  <hr style="width: 21%; height: 0.01em; position: absolute; left: 71.8%; top: 34.5%;">

  <hr style="width: 22%; height: 0.01em; position: absolute; left: 7.7%; top: 64.5%;">
  <hr style="width: 19%; height: 0.01em; position: absolute; left: 41.2%; top: 64.5%;">
  <hr style="width: 21%; height: 0.01em; position: absolute; left: 71.8%; top: 64.5%;">
</div>
```

here is a jsfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/Qc22p/

Comment: First of all I would advise using classes for common properties in order to facilitate debug. And from where I see it vertical lines have the sme problem as horizontal ones...

Comment: I can't see any problem with FireFox (latest version). Also, the HR tag should be self closing. `<hr />` to be XHTML compliant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So they do.  I suspect it may be a CSS "border style" or something which is intended to render as a 3D effect... grooved, ridged or somesuch.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp

**Yep, adding `border-style:solid;` fixed it.**

You may be able to find a prettier border-style.

Comment: it's something strange because i've noticed that the <hr> tag seems to always look for a border, It never likes to be a single line of 1px. When i gave it a border of 1px and a solid border style, it appeared as a 2px line, all because of the border (parallel lines) Maybe I need to try and use a different tag to do this?  I know that  using images is another option but I don't want to do that.

Comment: As MMM says, just use a border-top or a border-left;  1 side only, not 2 or 4 sides of the rectangle.

Comment: border-left: 1px solid #fff;  indeed fixed it! thanks Thomas!

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're seeing the `border`. Get rid of the 3D border and set a `border-top` for your horizontal lines and `border-left` for your vertical lines (e.g. `1px solid black`).

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying about the 3d style? It's the browser default styling for `hr` element, to apply yours, you can reset the default style using `border: 0;` or you can alter it by using `border: 1px solid #000` and you can set color accordingly

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qc22p/1/)

Comment: Why do you first reset the border and then set it anyway? Just leave the first statement out.

Comment: @MMM Do you see the difference between the default hr and my altered border hr?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for, all I'm saying is that you don't need the `border: none` statement because you're overriding it in the next line anyway (in your jsfiddle).

Comment: @MMM I got your point, but simply using `border-none` would make the hr disappear, what If op wants an height of hr element with a background color? So what I did was I resetted the default and used border solid to set it back, using border 0 is only sufficient when you are using background color and a height

Comment: You are mistaken, `border: none` gets **overridden** by your second statement. If you don't believe me, inspect the element using Developer Tools. Your `border: none` statement is crossed out. That's because you are specifying **the same** CSS property.

Comment: @MMM You don't understand, I just used both, 1st to reset, which op will use, 2nd to show that if you want to simply alter, so than you can use 2nd property straight away, what if I gave him simply this example? http://jsfiddle.net/Qc22p/7/ he won't get anything from it, so I used the second property just for explaining him

Comment: Ok, so you're showing two examples to him? Perhaps if you commented in the code it would be clearer. Otherwise he might think that he needs to use both statements.

Comment: This is not actually what I wanted, because as you see those are not thin 1px lines as I want, but no worries, I found that border-left: 1px solid #fff; is a solution.

Comment: @Conor Read CSS box-model, borders render outside element, hr having an height of 0, you use border simply means you are having a total of 2px and hence you get that thick line

Comment: @MMM I've mentioned it in my answer *You can alter it* :)

Comment: @Conor You never specified line thickening nor the bracket thing :) Edit: You deleted your comment, anyways didn't got what you had written